# how to make JLable visible and Translucent (almost invisible) on mouse hovering

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, repaint, translucency

I made a Wrappable `JLabel` which shows text message within the label with multiple lines.
The label and text (i.e. foreground and background) are visible all time.

Now I want to change the `JLabel` such that it should be visible only after mouse hover and 
rest of the time it should be translucent. How can I achieve this? please help me .. 
thanks in advance .

Comment: Let me be more specific this time. i had swing Layer component on which there is lable wich has some text. the layer is actually the video, now i want to make lable transperent by default so that user can see the video, but when user move mouse over that lable it show the text, i had not get any specific ans , please help me if any one know how to tackle it

Answer (score 1):

For mouse hover over the `JLabel` you have to call `repaint()` in all methods from [MouseXxxListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html), reason is the this notifier isn't implemented in the [JLabel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), more inc. descriptions in the [post by @kleopatra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7634488/714968)

Comment: but how should i make it transperent so  i can able to see the existing back ground

Comment: method setOpaque just make the lable area whitish and we see the white box instead of the image which is in background on which lable is present

Comment: Thanks guys for the support. i had found out the way to do it. just like to share it how i done, to make translucent i just make the alpha number of color of background and foreground change on mouse over and i was able to acheived the reqired effect.